# Oracle APEX - apex_application.g_print_success_message displays the message twice on refresh

Tags: oracle-apex-5.1

I am utilizing `apex_application.g_print_success_message` in one of my APEX processes to display a message to the user.

The process gets executes on page submit when `Request=VALUE1`.

The code checks if a variable is greater than 0, then displays a message. So the message is supposed to only be displayed when `Request=VALUE1` and if :P1_ITEM > 0:

```
BEGIN
      IF TO_NUMBER(:P1_ITEM) > 0 THEN
            apex_application.g_print_success_message := 'Test';
      END IF;
      :P_ITEM := 0;
END;
```

After displaying the message I set the page item to zero.

I submit the page, process executes, message gets displayed. Everything works fine. But then if I go ahead and refresh the page, the message displays again. Not sure why as one of the conditions is `TO_NUMBER(:P1_ITEM) > 0` and I did set it to 0. Also when I do a refresh the request cannot be `VALUE1` so I know the process does not get executed. But then why is the message getting displayed again?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with clear session state process?

Or maybe

[image]

Comment: On what do I set this condition?

Comment: In process section create a process called "Clear session state", over the section "Server side condition" put the condition

Comment: I tried that, except I used P1_NEW Item != 0 but it did not help. But I also noticed that P1_NEW is already set to 0. Out of curiosity I changed the condition to Item = Value and set value to 0 but still - nothing changed